# Ubiquity installer reboots on selecting "Install alongside Windows"

Tags: ubiquity

I currently run windows 7 32 bit.  I downloaded ubuntu 12.10 iso from http://www.ubuntu.com/ then I burned it to a dvd.  I tried to install it and everything goes fine until I reach the option *install ubuntu alongside windows 7* then on clicking continue the DVD ejects itself and "please remove the installation source from the tray" appears on the screen, and again windows starts and the installation remains incomplete.

I then created a bootable USB and tried to install but again on the same option installation stops.  I'm not an advanced user so the "try something else option" looks too complicated. I tried to use it but I dont know how to use this option.  How can I install ubuntu? Is it that windows 7 is not allowing me to install ubuntu or is the problem something else?

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted. Facing exactly the same problem. Running wubi.exe from the stick is just asking me to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

It's been so long since I've duel booted Windows, but I do believe that current Ubuntu distros can be installed from with in Windows via wubi. This page may help:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows

Start up Windows and pop in the ubuntu dvd, or the usb to make things a lot faster. Wubi may autorun if you're using the liveCD, and if you're using the usb just open it up and click on the wubi icon.

FYI, installing Ubuntu then Windows usually messes up the boot loader (grub) and will only boot Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll have to use the "something else" option BUT be careful: you may loose everything on your disk.

So, here's a step by step way of installing Ubuntu alongside Windows:

1. Backup everything important on your disk. Hopefully unnecessarily but better safe than sorry.
2. Boot windows and start the partition tool. Reduce the size of the Windows partition to create space for Ubuntu. 50Gb is recommended, minimum is 4Gb but in my option it is very limiting. You may need to create an extended partition if you already have 3 primary partitions and then create logical partitions, because you can only have a maximum of 4 primary partitions.
3. Boot from your liveDVD or live USB and choose the something else option.
4. When you arrive at the partitioning stage, create two partitions in the empty space. One large partition type ext4, mount point / and one 3 or 4 Gb "swap" partition. Swap is virtual memory. Not strictly necessary but recommended.
5. When you arrive at the bootloader stage, make sure you could the right disc. On Windows drives are labelled C,D,E etc. On Linux it is sda, sdb for the drive and sda1, sda2 etc for the partitions of the respective drives. Make sure you choose the right disc. If your Ubuntu is on sda3, then install the bootloader (Grub) on sda.
6. Finish installation and reboot.

Answer (score -1):

Its not that windows is not allowing you, try use Linux Live usb creator to create image on the usb and install ubuntu in a separate drive that is not containg windows.Use ext4 partition for intalling ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you have to use the option "something else" and manually create partitions, and select the option to put the boot loader on C drive (which in Linux is sda...note: not sda1 or sda2, just put it under sda).

There are good guides available if you google for dual-boot.